# Can there exist an $\omega$-Moti Gitik model?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

[Moti Gitik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moti_Gitik) had prove that there exists a model of ZF in which every aleph bigger than $\aleph_0$ is of $\aleph_0$ cofinality, call such models as Moti Gitik models.

> Supposing that there exists an $\omega$-model of ZF. Would it follow that there can exist an $\omega$-Moti Gitik model.

An $\omega$-model is a model in which all naturals are the standard naturals as externally seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gitik's model is obtained by forcing methods, these do not change the ordinals, so in particular preserve things like $\omega$-model.

However, the requirements for Gitik's model are currently not known to be weaker than "a proper class of strongly compact cardinals", which exceed "there is an $\omega$-model" by *a lot*. And while it is conjectured that a similar result can be obtained with a lot less than even a single strongly compact, we do know that it implies there are many Woodin cardinals in an inner model, so you cannot bring this result anywhere near "there is an $\omega$-model".

Comment: Is there a shortish explanation of why even a single strongly compact is expected to be overkill? That's surprising to me at least.

Comment: @Noah: There's no real explanation. We know that $\omega$-Woodins are equiconsistent with "all the $\aleph_n$'s have countable cofinality (force over models of AD to signularise $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_2$), so one expect this to "more or less" continue upwards. But I hazard a guess that in order to achieve these results by forcing methods we probably need much larger cardinals than Woodin cardinals. So there's really a new technology that's hiding from us.

Comment: Fair. Do we even know how to get countable cofinality of all $\aleph_\alpha$s with $\alpha\le\omega+2$ from less than a strongly compact? (Not sure why I'm settling on *that* as my next question, but meh, this isn't my competence realm anyways.)

Comment: @Noah: Well, I don't know. I'm sure the AD people can give an easier answer about stretching the singularity of cardinals beyond $\aleph_\omega$. But we don't even know how to get two successive singulars directly from a single Woodin cardinal (+ sharp, measurable, another Woodin cardinal, if that makes your life easier). I had a dream that Ralf Schindler had a paper where he in fact solved that, but after two years of telling people about it Yair Hayut suggested we read the paper and it turned out to be a dream. Ralf asked if I remember the proof, but clearly I didn't.

Comment: I see, thanks! (And re: a pair of successive singulars: no, that doesn't make my life easier. :P)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, just to make sure, your answer is to the positive, that is there can be an $\omega$-Gitik model of $\sf ZF$. What is the least large cardinal hypothesis that assures that?

Comment: @Zuhair: Proper class of strongly compact cardinals.